# How to make sure webpack watches files importanted in a file of another programming language loaded by a loader

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to create a loader to run files in a different language and return js. It works fine but I'm having watching the changes on them.

I found a [repo that does this for python](https://github.com/martim00/python-webpack-loader) and while this is a interesting example it still have the issue I'm having.

Following the code in the repo, what I'd like to do is:

```
// my webpack entry
import Hello from './hello.py'

document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = Hello.hello_world();
```

Whenever I change hello.py the python loader runs again and everything works perfectly.

Now, let's say I have a python module inside of it.

```
# runs with transcrypt
import world

def hello():
   return "Hello " + world.world();

module.exports = {"hello_world": hello}
```

When I change world.py webpack watcher doesn't know it needs to apply the loader to hello.py again.

What are the possible solutions for this? Is there a way the loader could register new files to be watched?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/

Comment: Thanks, I was able to make it watch world.py but it didn’t update hello.py. I guess I’m missing something.

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer is this.addDependency.

The dev would need to send as source not only the desired content but also a list of the python dependencies for that source (or parse the source for them).

Inside the loader, the dev needs to loop through them and call this.addDependency for each one.